# How many time the name "Allah" comes in Holy Quran?

Tags: quran, allah, history, islamic-philosophy

The name "ALLAH" comes in holy Quran how many time .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name **الله** appears in the Quran 2699 times, excluding **اللَّهُمَّ** which appears 5 times. See [corpus.quran.com](http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=Alh)

Comment: Hm... I wonder if that is correct I guess they might have counted لله too which basically is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The name "ALLAH" COMES in Quaran in 2698 times

Comment: If you don't count the Bismillah as part of Surah Fatiha.

Answer (score -2):

Allah name in quran is exactly 2584 times written

Comment: What is the basis of your count?

Answer (score -2):

You need to count Bismillah (has Allah) 2698-2584= 114. Surah # 9 Tauba, does not begin with Bismillah. So somewhere 1 is missing to account for.

Comment: How do you come to this conclusion? Surah al-Mujadalalah has the name "Allah" in each verse so you certainly have much more than 114 times "Allah" in the qur'an.